# Unable to find type [System.Web.HttpUtility] in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure, microsoft-translator

I'm trying to obtain an access token for a Microsoft Translator application by using PowerShell, but certain commands in the process fail as a result of the error:

```
Unable to find type [System.Web.HttpUtility]
```

Before receiving this error, I copied and pasted the code from [this MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454950.aspx) into the PowerShell ISE, and replaced the placeholder values with my actual credentials:

```
# ...
$ClientID = '<Your Value Here From Registered Application>'
$client_Secret = ‘<Your Registered Application client_secret>'

# If ClientId or Client_Secret has special characters, UrlEncode before sending request
$clientIDEncoded = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($ClientID)
$client_SecretEncoded = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode($client_Secret)
# ...
```

What additional code do I need to add for this to work?

Comment: did u already see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27898258/httputility-not-recognised-in-net-4-5

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You need to load the `System.Web` assembly. Use the `Add-Type` cmdlet like so,

```
PS C:\> [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("www.google.com")
Unable to find type [System.Web.HttpUtility].

PS C:\> Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
PS C:\> [System.Web.HttpUtility]::UrlEncode("www.google.com")
www.google.com
```